# Custom Data Validation: runtime error 450

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been trying to add data validation in one of my macros that moves a line of data into the next tab.

I've looked on here and elsewhere for syntax etc. and think I should have the application right. The main issue is whenever I run the macro I get "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

The relevant part of the macro is as follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

Dim RngP As Range, RngQ As Range

With ThisWorkbook.SHEETS(4) 'The code only fires if they confirm - if not, the line will remain in Pipeline.
            Dim RowToPasteTo As Long
            RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("P" & RowToPasteTo).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC[8]="""",RC[-3]-RC[-1]-RC[9],""""),"""")" 'Creates the budget Overhead Formula
            .Range("Q" & RowToPasteTo).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-4],"""")" 'Creates the percentage of budget used formual


            Set RngP = .Range("P" & RowToPasteTo).Range 'Setting variable to new budget overhead cell
            Set RngQ = .Range("Q" & RowToPasteTo).Range 'Setting Variable to new  Budget Used cell
            RngP.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=""" 'Making data validation lock in the formula
            RngQ.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=""" 'Making data validation lock in the formula

  End With
End Sub
```

The error seems to apply to the lines `Set RngP = .Range("P" & RowToPasteTo)` and the next three lines.

What I'm aiming for is to set the data validation on the new P & Q cells with formulas, to a custom validation of ="" to stop others changing the formula.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The error cannot apply to more the one line! It's hit in one statement and you should have the offending line highlighted

Comment: anyhow, just use `Set RngP = .Range("P" & RowToPasteTo)`

Comment: Hi, 
I know it's with that line, but it is also the second Set RngQ because if I comment out the P line the error also applies there)

Comment: I have followed your advice and now have errors on the next two lines (which is why I said the four lines in total).. 
For ```RngP.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="="""``` I have now come up with a run time error 1004, Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

Comment: Make sure there is no datavalidation in `RngP` before you add one. Delete the old one before adding or you get an error.

Comment: _"because if I comment out the P line the error also applies there) "_, but the Q line was the same as the P -> I took it for granted you'd have applied the same fix

Comment: _"and now have errors on the next two lines (which is why I said the four lines in total)."_: those two lines are directly related to `RngP` and `RnQ` -> no wonder they error out if you don't define those ranges! And the logic can be applied further: if you take the foundations out of a home, it's for sure the home will fall down… So take care of the foundations first!

Comment: I have applied it to both, now that a solution is provided. Not sure why I am still getting the problem with the next two lh the next two lines now I've set the ranges?

Comment: I think I may have poorly worded y comments.

The P Line error was before I saw your solution, and once there was a fix for Q then I applied it to P as well so tthat wasn't an issue. 

But even with these changes, there is an error on ```RngP.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="="""```
It says Run Time Error 1004 Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Comment: @Breakingfaith have you made sure that any existing datavalidation in that range is beeing deleted before you add a new one?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, I've put itn a ```RngP.Validation.Delete``` and the same for Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Formula1:="="""` is no valid validation forumla. The formula must according to the documentation [Validation.Add method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.add) result in `True` or `False`.

So replace it with `Formula1:=rngP.Address(False, False) & "="""`. You somehow need an address in the formula that `""` is compared to.

Answer (score 0):

cheers to @HTH re the first part of the answer.

The final issue I had with runtime error 1004, was that I had not put in enough quotation marks.

So where I had: `RngP.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="="""`

I should have had  `RngP.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=""=""""`

Comment: Note that `"" = """"` is always `False` and therefore the same as `Formula1:=False`. This is very likely not what you wanted. Check my solution.